# What is the correct way to use OpacityFunctionScaling with DensityPlot3D?

Tags: opacity, plotting

I am trying to plot solution of heat PDE in 3D. Inside a cylinder.

To do this, I am using `DensityPlot3D`. But I am having hard time getting the colors to show in more realistic way that reflects the temperature in different parts of the inside of the cylinder. If I use the default setting, the density shows all in one color while the color legend has color spectrum which has more variations in it.

Here is a very simple example of what I mean. The Cylinder has height 3 and radius 1.

```
(*assume this is the current temperature at some time instance*)
f[x_,y_,z_]:=Sin[Pi Sqrt[x^2+y^2]]*Sin[z/3 *Pi] 

DensityPlot3D[f[x,y,z],
   Element[{x, y, z},Cylinder[{{0,0,0},{0,0,3}},1]],
   PlotRange->{All,All,All},
   PlotLegends->Automatic,
   SphericalRegion->True,
   OpacityFunction->Automatic,
   (*OpacityFunctionScaling->Function[f,f],*) (* need to figure this one*)
    AxesLabel->{"x","y","z"},
    BaseStyle->12]
```

which gives

[image: Mathematica graphics]

Why is the blue coloring not showing in the actual plot? For example, looking at the how the temperature changes at some section of the cylinder (the middle of the cylinder) gives

```
Table[f[x, 0, 1.5], {x, -1, 1, .1}] // Chop

{0, 0.309017, 0.587785, 0.809017, 0.951057, 1., 0.951057, 
 0.809017, 0.587785, 0.309017, 0, 0.309017, 0.587785, 0.809017, 
 0.951057, 1., 0.951057, 0.809017, 0.587785, 0.309017, 0}
```

So temperature is zero at edge of cylinder , zero again at center and higher in between.  So one expects to see blue color showing near the edge and blue in middle and hotter color elsewhere?

temperature is also zero at top and bottom of the cylinder. But this plot does not reflect this:

[image: Mathematica graphics]

How to change `OpacityFunctionScaling` to reflect this? Or do I need to do something else?